# The best data storage format in term of weight and performance (e.g., Txt, Asc, Bin, etc.)?

Tags: performance, format

Can someone guide me to find the best storage format in term of read/write speed, performance, weight (file size) in order to store heavy matrices (of floating numbers with a constant precision) into a file (to HDD).

I have been using ASCII, Text and Binary format. And lets say for the same matrix size (e.g. 10000x10000x200) and numbers precision (e.g., 5 significant digits) I found that Binary format gave the best results in general, then ASCII and Text in term of speed of access/write and weight in general (I haven't do any actual testing).

With that being said, is there a standard data storage format better then binary in my situation? If not, Is there any way I can optimize my data structure to get better performances while saving/reading?

PS. I can use C, C++ or Matlab (doesn't matter which one for me) if one can help reaching better results.

Comment: Weight/performance: binary.  Accessibility: text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Binary will be much faster in general. If you are using floats, you are using 4 bytes per number, instead of 1 byte per character of the number - so the number 5.34182 is 4 bytes instead of 7 bytes plus a delimiter.

Going further though, you can probably do better. Your disk doesn't read data byte by byte, rather it reads data in [blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_%28data_storage%29), and generally you want to avoid reading more blocks than you have to. The real reason that binary format is faster isn't that it takes fewer bytes, but that it takes fewer blocks (a product of taking fewer bytes). What this means is that you want to minimize the size on disk, because reading from a disk is an order of magnitude slower than  reading from RAM - disk accesses are measured in milliseconds, while RAM accesses are in microseconds.

So now what you can do? If your matrix is [sparse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix), you can store just the elements that are non-zero, which will save you a lot of space. So instead of storing each point, store a pair of (index, value) for each entry. This means that each entry is now 8 bytes instead of 4, but if more than half of the matrix is zero, you save a lot of space.

Finally, compression can help a lot here. Of course more compression means more CPU time to decompress the matrix, but it can also mean faster disk reads. Here, you really have to experiment - at the simple end of the spectrum, [Run Length Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) is easy to implement and often works surprisingly well. This works because if you are storing for small integers and "simple" floats, most of the bytes are zero. This also works well if the same number is repeated multiple times, which does happen in matrices. I'd also recommend checking out more advanced schemes, such as [bzip2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bzip2), which while more computationally complex, could significantly decrease the size on disk. Alas, compression tends to be very domain specific, so you have to experiment here. What works in one domain doesn't always work in another.

Comment: Compression is a win for slow storage (i.e. tape drives or network shares), but not likely to keep up with a modern local hard disk, especially once the OS disk cache comes into play.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I disagree, at least partially. A lot of commonly used matrices are highly compressible, and even with clever hard drives, if you can get significant compression (ie. in a giant, very sparse matrix), you still see big gains. A 32mb disk cache is only going to store a raw 3000x3000 matrix of 4 byte entries, and - admitting that I don't know a ton about modern disk caching - I feel like if you were several times the size of the disk cache size, you would see big slow downs.

Comment: @mdkess: In cases of extreme sparsity, you wouldn't want to decompress it at all, but process it sparse.  And modern OSes frequently use gigabytes of RAM for disk cache.

Answer (score 1):

Complex question.  And many people have been there in terms of libraries blending efficiency with ease of use and interchange -- did you consider things like [hdf5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/) or [NetCDF](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/) ?  Both of these have libraries for C/C++ access, as well as bindings to the common tools such as Matlab, Python, R, ...

That said, I have written one-off binary savers in the past too.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick replay. It seems that for large files (>1Gb) HDF5 is the choice to go with. As I am not sure my files will be of that size, I will do some testing. The other thing which is not clear for me, can you tell if HDF5 is based on or is actually binary format? -Thanks

Comment: @Maiss: All formats are binary eventually, with some sort of structure added on top.  HDF doesn't use ASCII characters to encode numeric data, from that perspective it is more binary than a textual format.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the 64mb of disk cache wont be helping much in my case.

Unfortunately, I am working with very dense matrices (finite elements with strong bindings) and Binary with a limited precision seems to give the best performance in term of read/write speed and files size (much lighter) with no compression possible.

Text format resulted in much heavier files size compared to Binary, however after compression the resulting files size is the same as Binary, but required considerable compression time. The read/write time is extremely higher too.

For 3000x3000 (single): the Binary (68Mb) read/write time was: 0.05/0.23s and 13.8/6.5s for Text (145Mb).
For 6000x6000 (single): the Binary (274Mb) read/write time was: 0.22/0.92s and 56/26s for Text (583Mb). However these values may not be accurate as the HDD may be an important limiting factor for me.

Tests were made using the same precision (different combinations), same matrix size (3000x3000, 6000x6000, 12000x12000) and same CPU affinity and using the standard Matlab [Fwrite](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/f16-5702.html#f16-14516), [Fprintf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/f16-5702.html#f16-14516), Fread and Fscanf. I couldn't get higher size/precision as the HDD read/write speed was limiting and the CPU at the border line.